# How to get cookies in angular run function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am setting cookies after response comes from server side(setting cookies is 0k), when i get cookies in angular run function , i am not able to get cookies ,

Here is my code,

```
 $scope.LoginIn=function(email_id,password){

        if($rootScope.login=="login"){
            myEl.html('');
        }
        loginServices.SignIn(email_id, password).then(respSuccess, respError);
    }
    function respSuccess(resp) {

        alert(JSON.stringify(resp));

        $cookieStore.put("rePopulate", resp);
        $cookies.put("userName", resp.data.user.name);

        var token = resp.data ? resp.data.token : null;


        if (token) {
            LocalStorage.set("t",resp.data.token);
            $rootScope.modalInstance.close();
            $rootScope.login=resp.data.user.name;
            $rootScope.isloggedIn=true;
            $rootScope.customlogin=true;

        }
    }
    function respError(resp) {
        if(resp.data.success='false'){
            $scope.msg='Invalid Credentials';
        }
    }
```

Here i am getting cookies .

```
homepal.run(function run($http, $cookies,$rootScope,$location){

    if($rootScope.login=undefined || $rootScope.login=="login"){
        $rootScope.isloggedIn=false;
    }
    $rootScope.isloggedIn=true;
    $rootScope.login=$cookies.get('username');
    alert($rootScope.login);

});
```

It saying undefined .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry its spelling mistake . It

```
$cookies.put("username", resp.data.user.name);

$rootScope.login=$cookies.get('username');
```